# Reference Required for Assembly that is definitely part of a project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, linq-to-sql, webforms

I have a project that I am in the process of migrating to using Linq To SQL. On the whole it's fine, but I'm stuck on an issue where if I try to put a timestamp from an DTO into a hidden field I get this error at runtime:

> BC30652: Reference required to assembly 'System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' containing the type 'System.Data.Linq.Binary'. Add one to your project.

I definitely have a reference to the assembly, otherwise other sections of the code wouldn't compile. I tried removing all references and deleting the bin and obj folders, but I still get the same error.

It happens on this line in the markup:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfTimestamp" runat="server" 
    Value='<%#CType(Container.DataItem, CommunicationType).pslTimestamp.TimestampToString() %>' />
```

Where TimestampToString is an extension method that looks like this:

```
<Extension()> _
Public Function TimestampToString(ByVal binary As Binary) As String

    Return BitConverter.ToUInt64(binary.ToArray(), 0).ToString()

End Function
```

Has anyone seen this kind of behavior and know a fix to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you separating you logic in an different assembly? If so then you must reference it in the  web app also. You can add it to the web.config

```
 <compilation debug="true">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Comment: I added the last two assemblies you listed and it now works, which is odd since the same assemblies are in the project references.

Answer (score 2):

I had this happen related to code modules that were part of the project. What solved it was closing the solution and reopening it. I had been debugging an ASPX project that was upgraded, and had eliminated all of the errors, only to have this issue pop up at the end.